# Misplaced text on privilege information pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, information-display, privileges-page

Open up a privilege breakdown from the [list of privileges on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

For this example, I'll use [Vote Up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

The "Privilege Type:" text should be before its related symbol. Instead, it's after.

[image]

This appears to be cross-network, as it is also displayed this way on [Stack Overflow's Vote Up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) page. (Dark mode appears to be irrelevant)

[image]

Comment: Similar Q&A on RSO's meta: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10351/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5/10352#10352

Comment: [Freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775) would actually be useful (they don't have to be ugly). It is not clear what symbol is referred to.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I'd edit some in, but the problem's already been fixed. The issue was that the symbol (the little up down arrows) should be after the "Privilege type:" text. Simply put, the order of the text was swapped. It should be "Privilege type: (symbol) Moderation privilege"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build. Thanks for the report!

Kind of a funny problem here. The icon and the type description used to be rendered via a helper function. There are no helpers in .NET Core, so it was replaced with a function that ended up writing markup out immediately when called when what we actually wanted was to use it as a parameter to our translation engine:

```
@functions {
    string PrivilegeIcon(Privilege privilege)
    {
        // var title = ...;
        <i title="@title"></i>@title
        return null;
    }
}

@_m("Privilege type: $icon$", new { icon = PrivilegeIcon(Model.SelectedPrivilege.Privilege) })
```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for sharing the code as well.

Comment: Prototypical side effects?