# Markdown help page is broken (badly presented/formatted) on every site

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, editing-help

In the [Markdown help](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/editing-help#italics-bold) I see:

[image]

Is that what the help is supposed to say and look like? Because it doesn't make sense to me.

As animuson points out in a comment, all of the highlighted example text is being shifted to the very left of each line. The entire page is broken.

Comment: All of the highlighted example text is being shifted to the very left of each line. The entire page is broken.

Comment: The same is true with the help on this Meta site, and on Stack Overflow -- https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build. Thanks for the report!

This was caused by the same problem as reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347291)... gotta love framework migrations.

Comment: When will the next build be deployed (i.e. when may I inspect the result of the fix)?

Comment: @ChrisW It's out now. We usually deploy a few times a day, but I was posting that at the end of my workday, so figured a new build would happen in the morning (and it did).